# Python read and write 2 DBs

Tags: python, mysql, postgresql, grails

I have never really used python before.
Before getting into it, I had a quick question to check the feasibility of something I am planning to do here.

I have two servers, **MySQL server and postgresql cluster** (greenplum prod)

Now, I need to run a python script to read data from greenplum and write it into the mysql server into three tables (Insert tables here)

Initially, I was doing all of it within greenplum prod only, it used to read data and created three intermediate tables within greenplum prod only.
Now, I need these three intermediate tables to created and updated every hour in the mysql server and this can happen only within one python script (as it's read & write )

Is this process feasible?

If it is, my grails application will be reading the data from mysql server(dynamic data) and displaying it in the browser
The grails application cannot connect to greenplum prod due to firewall issues and it will put too much load on the server also, which are the reasons for this entire process

All approaches/suggestions are most welcome

Answer (score 1):

you can achieve this using two things [mysql library](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/MySQL-python/) and [docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/index.html) and [cron job](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/config/cron) and [other link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11774925/how-to-run-a-python-file-using-cron-jobs)

1. Use Mysql library to create and update the data in mysql database
2. then Cron job that run the above script every one hours to do same operation repeteadly