# How to automate the execution of .py file

Tags: python

I have a test.py file that I execute in my terminal with

```
 python test.py
```

what I would like to do is to have this file automatically execute at 1:00 am everyday. How can I implement this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to run a python file using cron jobs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11774925/how-to-run-a-python-file-using-cron-jobs)

Comment: This is not a programming question actually - this kind of problem is solved using your OS scheduler.

Comment: You can take a look at `cron`

Answer (score 2):

If you are using linux you can have a look about [`at`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man1/at.1posix.html) to execute at a specific time.

you can also use [`watch`](http://www.linfo.org/watch.html)

But maybe [`crontab`](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CronHowto) is better in this case.

Answer (score 1):

`crontab` is better option for this use case. You can add your command in cron job using following command. It will execute your python script at 1:00am every day.

```
crontab -e
```

write following lines :

```
00 01 * * * python /path/to/python/script
```