# cron expression in python file

Tags: python, cron

I have a requirement in which need to schedule one activity on monthly basis and to do that by python script. Basically I will trigger a cron expression inside the python script.
I am new to python. Want expert's advice on whether this is feasible? If so, do I need any modules such as *python-crontab*?

Comment: this will help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11774925/how-to-run-a-python-file-using-cron-jobs

Comment: You would use cron to schedule the running of a python script, you wouldn't use python to trigger a cron expression indie the python script

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to run a python file using cron jobs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11774925/how-to-run-a-python-file-using-cron-jobs)

Comment: No. I will explore further and get back.