# Checking if a list of YouTube videos still online with Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to check if a list of 4 YouTube videos still online. I know one of them is offline, and from time to time I want to see if any action was made upon the others. Searching through the web and with a little coding (I'm a beginner) I made this:

```
import requests
from pprint import pprint

videos = ["id1","id2","id3","id4"]

for i in videos:
    id_of_video = i
    your_api_key = 'myapi' 
    url = 'https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?id={}&key={}&part=status'.format(id_of_video, your_api_key)
    url_get = requests.get(url)
    pprint(url_get.json())
```

The code runs well and I receive something like this (I copied just two results):

```
{'etag': 'somenumbersandcharactershere',
 'items': [{'etag': 'somenumbersandcharactershere',
            'id': 'videoid',
            'kind': 'youtube#video',
            'status': {'embeddable': True,
                       'license': 'youtube',
                       'madeForKids': False,
                       'privacyStatus': 'public',
                       'publicStatsViewable': True,
                       'uploadStatus': 'processed'}}],
 'kind': 'youtube#videoListResponse',
 'pageInfo': {'resultsPerPage': 1, 'totalResults': 1}}

{'etag': 'somenumbersandcharactershere',
 'items': [],
 'kind': 'youtube#videoListResponse',
 'pageInfo': {'resultsPerPage': 0, 'totalResults': 0}}
```

One of them is online and the other one is not. Great.

But I want to create a code that check it for me from time to time and says: "This video ID is not available anymore". But I don't know how.

My main task right now is to print a message for each video ID! So, let's say: "ID1 is on-line" and "ID2 is offline".

I thought about creating an if statement to check the results of the "url_get.json()" tag but it only holds the last video ID...

If I run

```
url_get.json()
```

I get only the last ID from the list.

Comment: So, you want to `print` a `'message'`, only `if` the value of `your_json['pageInfo']['totalResult']` is `== 0`?

Comment: you can create a cron job for this or create a bot that will do this for you

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11774925/how-to-run-a-python-file-using-cron-jobs

Comment: @Grismar yes. Actually, I want to print a message for each video ID! So, let's say: "ID1 is on-line" and "ID2 is offline".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a dictionary for this. At first, I set the values to `None`. Then, when looping through the dictionary, I set the values to the returned JSON. At the end of the program, I print `IDx is offline or online`. You can do whatever you want with the data in the dictionary though.

```
import requests
from pprint import pprint

videos = {"id1": None, "id2": None, "id3": None, "id4": None}
for i in videos:
    id_of_video = i
    your_api_key = 'myapi' 
    url = 'https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?id={}&key={}&part=status'.format(id_of_video, your_api_key)
    url_get = requests.get(url)
    pprint(url_get.json())
    videos[i] = url_get.json()

for video in videos:
    if videos[video]["pageInfo"]["resultsPerPage"] == 0:
        print(f"{video.upper()} is offline")
    else:
        print(f"{video.upper()} is online")
```

Comment: @interferemadly, if this answered your question, please click the checkmark

Comment: Tried this, but received this error: 

`TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)

<ipython-input-50-3e2290602fff> in <module>

     12 

     13 for video in videos:

---> 14     if video[videos]["pageInfo"]["resultsPerPage"] == 0:

     15         print(f"{video.upper()} is offline")

     16     else:

TypeError: string indices must be integers`

Comment: @interferemadly fixed :)

Comment: hey man, I don't know if I'm missing something – as I said, I'm a beginner. Still getting and error: `TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-54-4c7fce7b6a05> in <module>
     11 
     12 for video in videos:
---> 13     if videos[video]["pageInfo"]["resultsPerPage"] == 0:
     14         print(f"{video.upper()} is offline")
     15     else:

TypeError: 'Response' object is not subscriptable`

Comment: now it should be fixed, I forgot to turn it into a json

Comment: Thanks, @KetZoomer. It worked. I will read the core carefully to understand better :)

Answer (score 0):

So you want to write a program that periodically pings Youtube. The easiest way to achieve it  would be something like

```py
from time import sleep

delay : int = 20

while True:
# ping YT here
  sleep(delay)
```

This will run it every 20 seconds.
There are a number of problems here.

- It runs forever
- The only way to stop program is by clicking Ctrl+C
- It also won't be exactly 20 seconds

But it will do the trick at first.
I found great question (thread???) [here at stackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/474528/what-is-the-best-way-to-repeatedly-execute-a-function-every-x-seconds)
The Answer proposes to use some more advanced concept of "event loop".
It's definitely worth getting into if you have time.

Comment: if server fails or system is shutdown then this won't work, program need to run again. better to create a cron job for this job

Comment: Thanks, this is part of the problem. But my main question is: how to check each ID and print a message for each one! So, let's say: "ID1 is on-line" and "ID2 is offline".

Comment: @CartesianCoordianateSystem, please read the question fully before answering